# Given that a power series Converges what conclusions can be made

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

suppose $\sum a_n(x-3)^n$ is a power series that converges at $x=5$ and diverges at $x=0$, will $\sum a_n(x-3)^n$ converge at $x=8$ and at $x=6$?

I know that $2 \leq R \leq 3$ and that both 8, and 6 are outside the interval of convergence given that it is centered at 3, so the series will diverge at those points. Is this correct?

Comment: If R=3, then x=6 is on the circle of convergence.  If $a_n$ forms an alternating sequence, then it will diverge at x=0, but converge at x=6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct about $8$, but not about $6$. With the information that you have provided, nothing can be asserted about the convergence at $6$. Note that the distance from $6$ to $3$ is equal to the distance from $0$ to $3$.